# Re allow app installation over wireless debugging after denying it | Android

Tags: android, debugging

I accidentally clicked on Deny on the installation prompt and now it is automatically denying all consecutive installation over wireless and USB debugging.

My phone is Android 11 and the laptop is running on Ubuntu 22.04.

Can someone please help me to allow installations again?

Comment: Go to Settings -> Developer options -> Revoke USB debugging authorizations. Try to install again dialog will should appear again

Comment: I did that and re-paired the device. Still does not work. Mind that when I denied the permission I was connected through wireless debugging, not USB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check once I have tried for Mi device.

**Go to Device settings-> search for install via USB(Security)->Click on that option and make disable toggle-> and reinstall app.**

Option 2-

**Go to Settings->Apps->Permissions->install via USB->Click on that option and make disable toggle-> and reinstall app.**

Comment: Thank you very much. The first option solved it.

Answer (score -1):

Just disable and re-enable the allow USB debugging option under the developer's settings on your phone

Comment: I did that. It didn't work. I removed all the paired devices from both my phone and laptop and re-paired them, it still made no difference.